# redirecting bots and crawlers to another but not human via htaccess

Tags: htaccess, web-crawlers, robots.txt, googlebot, facebook

I would to apply this diagram via htaccess I tried a lots of codes but I failed every time

[image]

So I need to redirecting bots and crawlers especially from facebook via `.htaccess`

Comment: Are you intending this site to be indexed by search engines? What are the domains/URLs for real visitors and bots respectively? Redirecting to one site before redirecting to another seems like one redirect too many - why do you need to redirect to site2 first?

Comment: well I will use site1 like a short link redirecting 301 to site2 , site2.com is the point of intersection between bot and human

Comment: site1.com and site2com for both and  as an example :  blog.com/folder/ for bots and games for real visitors at the end of redirecting site2.com

Comment: And what are the intended URLs for real-visitors and bots respectively? `site2.com/real` (or simply `site2.com`) and `site2.com/bots`? Or an entirely different domain again, as in your comment above (`blog.com`?) Do real visitors _need_ to redirect? And to clarify... are you including the main search engines in your "bots and crawlers"?

Comment: please check this website `http://GamingTutorials.net/BetaTesterGesucht` with redirect checker as an example to understand my idea , it will redirect you as a human to `.weebly.com` , but as a bot it will redirect you to another blog (different domain)

Comment: Why not just use ModSecurity and forget all this silliness??

Comment: @closetnoc ok,  can I control bots and crawlers with it ? I mean redirect them

Comment: No. You do not redirect them (though that may be possible), you block (manage) the bad bots, scrapers, hackers, and so on so that you do not *feel* like you need to redirect them. There is no sense of over-complicating things. Redirects cost not only resources, but also experience, performance, value, and trust.

Comment: well my main goal is to redirect them  and let them check another website to avoid suspicions

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do could technically be classified as cloaking which is a violation of Google's terms and can result in your site being removed from the Google index. Google is very strict in what they class as cloaking and basically the rule is whatever the end user sees the crawler has to see as well. If you are trying to block malicious bots then the easiest thing to do is simply block their user agent strings using .htaccess but if you try cloaking with a legitimate crawler such as Google it will be detected and will result in severe penalties and manual action notices which can severely affect your SERP ranking.

Google not only uses the known Googlebot user agent but also uses other bots which have the user agent string of real browsers on IP addresses not affiliated with Google as a way to detect this on websites so there is no way to prevent yourself from being caught out doing this.

Now having given that warning...

You mention Facebook crawler specifically. Facebook has three different user agents for crawling. `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` and `facebookexternalhit/1.1` which are used when a user shares your website to their wall and `Facebot` which is used to help improve advertising performance. Out of all of them only `Facebot` respects the robots.txt rule as the other ones are only triggered by a user action and so are treated the same as a web browser in effect. If you want to block any Facebook crawling simply add a .htaccess rule to detect these user agent strings and if they are detected either block them or return an error page that crawlers are not permitted. Trying to forward them to an alternate site with different content will simply complicate matters and could have the potential of reducing your SERP ranking due to not having context appropriate content on the pages that the Bots can access.

Comment: No need for "technically".   As far as Google is concerned, that is a "sneaky redirect" and explicitly against their webmaster guidelines: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604723?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have maybe the solution, try this (you can customize the list) :

```
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Abonti|aggregator|AhrefsBot|asterias|BDCbot|BLEXBot|BuiltBotTough|Bullseye|BunnySlippers|ca\-crawler|CCBot|Cegbfeieh|CheeseBot|CherryPicker|CopyRightCheck|cosmos|Crescent|discobot|DittoSpyder|DotBot|Download Ninja|EasouSpider|EmailCollector|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|EroCrawler|Exabot|ExtractorPro|Fasterfox|FeedBooster|Foobot|Genieo|grub\-client|Harvest|hloader|httplib|HTTrack|humanlinks|ieautodiscovery|InfoNaviRobot|IstellaBot|Java/1\.|JennyBot|k2spider|Kenjin Spider|Keyword Density/0\.9|larbin|LexiBot|libWeb|libwww|LinkextractorPro|linko|LinkScan/8\.1a Unix|LinkWalker|LNSpiderguy|lwp\-trivial|magpie|Mata Hari|MaxPointCrawler|MegaIndex|Microsoft URL Control|MIIxpc|Mippin|Missigua Locator|Mister PiX|MJ12bot|moget|MSIECrawler|NetAnts|NICErsPRO|Niki\-Bot|NPBot|Nutch|Offline Explorer|Openfind|panscient\.com|PHP/5\.\{|ProPowerBot/2\.14|ProWebWalker|Python\-urllib|QueryN Metasearch|RepoMonkey|RMA|SemrushBot|SeznamBot|SISTRIX|sitecheck\.Internetseer\.com|SiteSnagger|SnapPreviewBot|Sogou|SpankBot|spanner|spbot|Spinn3r|suzuran|Szukacz/1\.4|Teleport|Telesoft|The Intraformant|TheNomad|TightTwatBot|Titan|toCrawl/UrlDispatcher|True_Robot|turingos|TurnitinBot|UbiCrawler|UnisterBot|URLy Warning|VCI|WBSearchBot|Web Downloader/6\.9|Web Image Collector|WebAuto|WebBandit|WebCopier|WebEnhancer|WebmasterWorldForumBot|WebReaper|WebSauger|Website Quester|Webster Pro|WebStripper|WebZip|Wotbox|wsr\-agent|WWW\-Collector\-E|Xenu|Zao|Zeus|ZyBORG|coccoc|Incutio|lmspider|memoryBot|SemrushBot|serf|Unknown|uptime files" bad_bot
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} env=bad_bot
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.exemple.com/custom_page
```

Comment: This won't work as-is. You don't check an environment variable with mod_rewrite like that - the `RewriteCond` _condition_ will always fail since `env=bad_bot` is seen as a literal string and compared against the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` server variable (again, not what you are trying to do). (It looks like you are trying to borrow syntax from `mod_auth_...`?!). The `RewriteCond` directive should read something like `RewriteCond %{ENV:bad_bot} 1` instead. (Although, as already stated, trying to _redirect_ the bot is probably a bad idea to begin with - if anything it should simply be _blocked_.)